# prooving that a language of form 0^n where n is prime is neither regular nor context free

Tags: computer-science, automata, pumping-lemma

I am thinking on this for quite long,but still hasn't been able to go far on it.
The first step is easy considering any language of form o^M where M is a prime greater than what our opponent has given( lets say n).I am not able to figure out how we can prove from here that no matter how our opponent breaks the string we can always pump it to show it doesn't belongs to class of context free languages(and hence regular languages).

PS:Its not a homework question.I have already completed this course.Just trying to solve it as I wasn't able to solve it during my course term.

Comment: This question would have been perfect for the upcoming [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2). So, if you like to have a place for questions like this one, please go ahead and help this proposal to take off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the given language is context-free. Using the [pumping lemma for context-free languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages), you will get numbers x and y such that x, x+y, x+2y, x+3y, and so on, are all prime numbers. However, this is not possible, as there are arbitrarily large gaps between prime numbers (to prove this, consider the numbers n!+2, n!+3, .... n! + n, for any natural number n>=2 - they are all composite).

Another approach is to use the theorem that every context-free language over a unary alphabet is a regular language. Then consider how DFAs over a unary alphabet can look like: every state has exactly one outgoing edge. After eliminating unreachable states, states must be q_0, q_1, ... q_k, where the transition from q_i goes to q_{i+1}, for 1 <= i < k, and the transition from q_k goes to some state. q_0 is the initial state. Regardless of the set of final states chosen, this cannot accept { 0^n | n is a prime } - again use the fact that there are arbitrarily large gaps between prime numbers to get a contradiction.

Comment: When using Pumping Lemma, you can fix a word 0^n of suitable length and pick i specifically so that the pumped word has no prime length. i=0 might even work.